# .splice not removing elements

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to remove a discord ID from an array with .slice() and it works fine everywhere else in my code, but when I try to remove it from this specific array, it just doesn't remove it. I've tried many things to troubleshoot and nothing works. Even if I copy what the console says is in the array and put THAT in the .splice(), it still does not remove it

```
let botifymention = String(message.mentions.members.first()).slice(3,-1);
botifiedMembers.push(botifymention);
```

```
botifiedMembers.splice(String(message.mentions.members.first()).slice(3,-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Splice takes the index of an element and how many elements to remove

```
const index = botifiedMembers.indexOf(String(message.mentions.members.first()).slice(3,-1));
if (index > -1) {
  botifiedMembers.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(botifiedMembers);
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work. Just wondering though why I was able to get away with what I was doing for so long? In many parts of the bot I use splice like I did to get rid of a specific element.